# NodePort conflicts wiht kube-apiserver's hostPort

Tags: kubernetes, kube-apiserver, service-node-port-range

I have a healthy k8s cluster. The kube-apiserver is using port **8443**.
Then I do something like below. I create/edit a Sevice and assign a fixed nodePort **8443**, too.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
      nodePort: 8443
```

The cluster becomes unreachable. If I run command `kubectl get pods`. It returns `Unable to connect to the server: EOF`

Cause I need run kubectl command to change the nodePort back. But I cannot use kubectl. It becomes a dead loop. I have 2 questions.

1. What can I do to get my k8s cluster back?
2. Why kube-apiserver or other components doesn't prevent me to change the nodePort to **8443**? Indicate the port **8443** is already in use.

Comment: The service creation should fail if the port is used (see [API docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#serviceport-v1-core). If that doesn't happen, you might wanna open an issue on GitHub.
Though I think the api-server usually uses port 6443.

Comment: You might be able to talk to etcd directly, without using kubectl (see [etcd docs](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.4.0/dev-guide/interacting_v3/))

Answer (score 1):

> kube-apiserver pod is a static pod brought up by kubelet using /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml file on master nodes

> so you can edit /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml ,
> where 8443 port is referenced and change it to a unused port. so that kube-apiserver will be available on that port. ideally kubelet tries to restart a static pod when its manifest file is changed .

> you need to edit ~/.kube/config , where 'server' address needs to be changed to new port.

> delete the problematic nodeport service .

> revert your changes in /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml & .kube/config file    to go back to original port (8443)

Answer (score 0):

It should not be possible when port range is set with default `service-node-port-range` [api-server flag](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/).

> --service-node-port-range portRange     Default: 30000-32767
> A port range to reserve for services with NodePort visibility. Example: '30000-32767'. Inclusive at both ends of the range.

---

> What can I do to get my k8s cluster back?

You can change `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` file and reaplace all occurrences of `8443` to e.g. `6443`.

Then connect to apiserver with:

```
$ kubectl --server https://<ip>:6443 ...
```

Delete the `my-service` service and restore kube-apiserver.yaml file to its previous form.

---

> Why kube-apiserver or other components doesn't prevent me to change the nodePort to 8443? Indicate the port 8443 is already in use.

I don't think many people encounter this problem because people usually use api-server with default values of `--service-node-port-range` flag which is: `30000-32767`. In such case you would see this error:

```
The Service "my-service" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 8443: provided port is not in the valid range. The range of valid ports is 30000-32767
```

Probably the best thing you can do with it is to ask k8s developers on k8s github repo. Just [open an issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues) and as this question there.